# 24 V output from two 12 V batteries in series, charge them with 12 V in parallel

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, charger, solar-energy, solar-charge-controller

I have a solar charge controller which can charge 12 V batteries. I have two 12 V batteries which are connected in parallel.

I need to have 24 V output without using DC-DC step up converters. Can I connect two 12 V batteries in both parallel and series? Like first having a parallel connection, then having a series connection with some diodes to control the current/voltage flow. Is it possible? Are there some best practices?

The goal is to charge/discharge the batteries simultaneously.

Comment: "like first having a parallel then having a series connection" could you clarify this? Is there a switch or control circuit that will select one of the operating modes: charging or discharging?

Comment: There's no easy way around this. Either you wire them in parallel and use a DC-DC converter to generate the 24V, or in series and use a converter to charge the second battery, or have a changeover switch or relay that would prevent simultaneous charge and output operation.

Comment: You can charge in parallel then switch to use in series with what you have.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 That's the problem, I need to charge and discharge simultaneously.

Comment: Then you clearly have proposed an unworkable solution.  No PV specs for Voc, P,max, no MTTP controller, no 2V4 charger, no battery balancer and no educated research on these requirements.

Comment: "goal is do charge/discharge the batteries simultaneously." That "simultaneously" can mean two different things: 1) At any given time, the batteries are both charging and discharging (depending on the current in and out); 2) When charging, both are charging; when  discharging, both are discharging. Which of these 2 do you mean?

Comment: **IF** the charger is isolated you can apply it to one battery at a time. This is a nonideal arrangement and can cause issues with battery balance and management. | The simplest interface methods is a DPDT relay but, as above, the charger MUST be isolated.

Answer (score 1):

On the face of it, not really unless you use switches to take the batteries offline while you charge them.

Now if you can use 2 chargers, and the chargers have a floating (ungrounded) output, you could connect each one across each battery. If the batteries are to be kept online ensure that the charger has current limiting and reverse-current blocking.

Or, use 1 charger and use a DPDT relay to switch the charger between each of the batteries in turn. But then you have to control the relay...

Or, eBay your 12V unit and get a dual voltage unit like this one: https://www.altestore.com/store/charge-controllers/solar-charge-controllers/pwm-solar-charge-controllers/xantrex-solar-charge-controllers-pwm/xantrex-c35-charge-controller-35a-12-or-24v-solar-charge-controller-p2069/